# DbGeography + entity framework 5 + Silverlight + DomainService

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, domainservices

I have create Entity with DbGeography and add it to my Domainservice.
But my SL app didn't see this filed.
How can I use DbGeography in SL5 app?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use DbGeography in Silverlight.  It's not supported.  You'll have to convert the DbGeography to a string (Well Known Text), a byte[] (Well Known Binary), or your own custom representation and work with it in that format within the Silverlight application.